MongoDB SDK and NextJS Serverside rendering
all.
I am using NextJS 14 and the app router.
I have an image gallery.
The Gallery page is server-rendered.
    const Gallery = async () => {
  const { images } = await getImages();

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto px-4 py-8">
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold mb-8">Image Gallery</h1>
      <div>
        <ImageComponent initialImages={images} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Gallery;

getImages is a server action
"use server";
import clientPromise from "@/lib/mongodb";
import { GalleryImage } from "@/types/images";
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";

export async function getImages(): Promise<{ images: GalleryImage[] }> {
  const client = await clientPromise;
  const db = client.db("afakedb");
  const collection = db.collection("fakecollection");

  const rawImages = await imagesCollection.find({}).toArray();
  if (rawImages.length === 0) {
    throw new Error("Error getting images");
  }

  const images = rawImages
    .map((img) => ({
      _id: img._id.toString(),
      url: img.url,
      prompt: img.prompt,
      likes: img.likes || 0,
    }))
    .reverse();

  return { images };
}

Now, working locally this works absolutely fine. When a user lands on the gallery all images are there, but most importantly when a user creates an image and navigates to the Gallery the new image is there.
With this change, When I push out to my web app that is hosted on Vercel it seems the Gallery is not refreshed at any point. When landing on the Gallery page all the data is there, however, when the user creates an image and navigates back to the Gallery it is like the data is either cached or the call is not being made for some reason.
The image created gets updated in the MongoDB so I have no idea why it does not come back. For example, I can create an image in my Vercel hosted app and refresh my locally running app to see the image?
Seems to be some sort of issue with how the MongoSDK works being hosted with Vercel?
Any ideas?

didd you try locally in build mode as well. npm run build && npm start

I did not, however, I added in revalidatePath and all seems well. I think it comes down to how server pages are not re-rendered from a Link in the menu. But, revalidating seems to have fixed my issue.

So, I added revalidatePath() into my API routes which seems to have fixed all my issues.
Thanks.
